# How to change font-size of label in paper-badge?

Tags: html, css, polymer, paper-badge

The font-size of the label for paper-badge is 12px in the source code. I want to make a particular paper-badge element to have a font-size of 10px. The element looks like this:

```
<paper-badge id="unreadCount" for="myIcon" label="[[count]]"></paper-badge>
```

The relevant CSS looks like this:

```
paper-badge {
    --paper-badge-background: #DC5E13;
    --paper-badge-width: 14px;
    --paper-badge-height: 14px;
    --paper-badge-margin-left: 4px;
    /*--paper-badge-margin-top: 6px;*/
    /*--paper-badge {
        #badge {
            font-size: 10px;
        }
    }*/
}

#unreadCount {
    font-size: 10px !important;
}
```

You can see my attempt of setting the font-size in the commented out --paper-badge mixin. That didn't work, so I tried setting the font-size in the id CSS selector. There is no `--paper-badge-font-size` mixin which is why I don't just use that.

Even with the !important tag, I can see in the Styles tab of my developer tools that the `font-size: 10px !important;` is overwritten and stays as `font-size: 12px;` under `.paper-badge-0 #badge.paper-badge`. When I untick this, it then goes to the 10px that I set in the CSS selector.

Does anyone know the correct way to overwrite the default font-size?

Comment: Try `!important`, maybe?

Comment: Yeah I mentioned I tried that, but somehow it's overwritten.

Comment: Check the web inspector, it might not be applied to the right element.

Comment: I believe you're right. There seems to be a `<div id="badge" class="style-scope paper-badge">5</div>` element inside my paper-badge element, where 5 is the label for the badge. I'm not sure how to apply the font-size to this inner element.

Comment: target the `.paper-badge`.

Comment: Ohh I had the wrong syntax originally. You can see in my original post I had `--paper-badge { #badge { font-size: 10px}}`, but I forgot to put the colon after `--paper-badge:` and there isn't supposed to be the `#badge` part. Thank you!

Comment: you can answer your own question and set answer as accepted. So everyone knows this question has been already answered. (good for users who is looking for solution and users who want to help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out with help from TricksfortheWeb.

I added this mixin

```
--paper-badge: {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

to the `paper-badge` selector. So now it looks like this:

```
paper-badge {
    --paper-badge-background: #DC5E13;
    --paper-badge-width: 14px;
    --paper-badge-height: 14px;
    --paper-badge-margin-left: 4px;
    --paper-badge: {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
}
```